# Insert list of child objects when inserting parent in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy Parent and Child class as shown below. The relationship between two is one-to-many relationship.

```
class Parent():
    systemName = Column(type_=String(100), primary_key=True)
    startDate = Column(type_=DateTime)
    childs = relationship("Child")

class Child():
    systemName = Column(type_=String(100), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(type_=String(100))
    parentSystemName = Column(
        String(100),
        ForeignKey("Parents", ondelete="CASCADE")
    )
```

I have included 'childs' as a list of 'Child' in the response model. So when I fetch data from database for parent, the response is as below -

```
{
   "systemName":"62259fd1_79b5_42b9_8381_3c0f9a6be322",
   "startDate":"2020-09-12T19:24:58.357000",
   "childs":[
      {
         "systemName":"ee16d7df-748f-4766-8233-a2997adb09dd",
         "name":"Child1",
         "parentSystemName":"62259fd1_79b5_42b9_8381_3c0f9a6be322"
      },
      {
         "systemName":"89306f60-9ec2-497a-a18c-8e2bebb682ee",
         "name":"Child2",
         "parentSystemName":"62259fd1_79b5_42b9_8381_3c0f9a6be322"
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to know how can I use the same JSON structure as above (i.e. a list of child in parents) and add the records to the database.

```
obj_in_data = jsonable_encoder(obj_in)
db_obj = self.model(**obj_in_data)
db.add(db_obj)
db.commit()
db.refresh(db_obj)
```

Currently, when I'm trying to insert the data using the same structure of JSON as above using but I get an error -

**AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'**

Comment: What code do you have that throws that error? Do you try to initialize instances of Parent first? Like `Parent(my_json_obj)`? Or do you use something else?

Comment: I have updated my question and added the code. 'jsonable_encoder' converts a model to json which is exactly as mentioned in the question and db_obj is the parent sqlalchemy model instance. I get an error at line 2.

Answer (score 0):

Nitpick: the multiple of child is children.

Your `Parent` expects `children` to be a list of `Child`-instances, but they're not, of course. A possible workaround is to take the `__init__()` function and adjust it.

```py
class Parent():
    systemName = Column(type_=String(100), primary_key=True)
    startDate = Column(type_=DateTime)
    children = relationship("Child")

    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
       """Take the `children`, if passed, and cast it into an array of `Child`
       instances, if they are not already"""
       if 'children' in kwargs:
           children = kwargs.pop('children', [])
           kwargs['children'] = [
              Child(**child_or_data) if isinstance(child_or_data), dict) else child_or_data)
              for child_or_data) in children
           ]
       super(self, Parent).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This code executes just before a new `Parent` is created, takes the list of children, sees if they are objects, transforms them into `Child`ren if they are, and then just continues with the rest of the initialisation.